# How to create Object with mouse click LibGdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Class FirstTower:

```
public class FirstTower extends Sprite {

    private Map map;
    private Texture texture;
    private float transfer = 1000;
    private float hp;
    private float radius;


    public FirstTower(Map map) {
        this.texture = new Texture("square.png");
        this.map = map;
        this.hp = 100;
        radius = 40;
    }


    @Override
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        batch.draw(texture, Gdx.input.getX() - radius, transfer - Gdx.input.getY() - radius);
    }

    @Override
    public void updade(float dt) {

    }
}
```

I need simple to create example of this class (object of FirstTower) with mouse click on gamefield.
How can I do this?

Try to search, but not find anything useful.

Image of object follow with my cursor.

Here is screen when app is running:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the GDX InputProcessor. This is done by executing the following:
**Replace `MyClass` with the class you wish to create (FirstTower I believe)**

```java
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(new InputProcessor() {
    public boolean touchDown(int x, int y, int point, int button) {
        if (button == Input.Buttons.LEFT) {
            new MyClass();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

*Note: I have excluded the other methods when creating a new InputProcessor to keep this answer tidy, but you will need to implement those methods.*